# How to send a key in parameter in AFMultipartFormData AFNetworking 3

Tags: ios, asp.net, objective-c, multipartform-data, afnetworking-3

This is how I"m sending the request:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/API/Upload",BaseURLString];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];
    NSError *error;
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;
for(NSData *eachImage in self.fetchedAtt) {
NSString *mystring = @"786";
        NSURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:string parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
[formData appendPartWithFormData:eachImage name:@"myImage"];
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:[mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                        name:@"PracticeCode"];
} error:&error];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }

            NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        }];
        [task resume];
    }
}
```

Sometimes I get:

> {   "Message": "Error writing MIME multipart body part to output
>   stream." }

//this is a 500 error
and sometimes I get

> Request failed: unsupported media type (415)

Comment: append this one is parameter mystring

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sorry I didn't get what you said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send multiple files in a single multiform request. Multipart doesn't work like this. You will have to make multiple multipart requests with 1 file at a time. So consider you have 20 files. You will create an async task that takes one file at a time, uploads it, and then performs the same function again for the next files.

And if you want to keep the references, you should return the file ids from the backend, and then append all the ids in a single array and send that array as a param in a separate api request to link the files with any object. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Afnetworking 3.0

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/API/Upload",BaseURLString]; parameters:@{@"text":@"name"} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

         [formData appendPartWithFileData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]] name:@"bizcard" fileName:@"Businesscard.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"]; // you file to upload
        } error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
    uploadTask = [manager
                  uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                  progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      });
                  }
                  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                      if (error) {
                          NSLog(@"Error: %@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[[error valueForKey:@"userInfo"] valueForKey:@"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                          callback(NO,nil);
                          [UtilityClass removeActivityIndicator];

                      } else {
                          callback(YES,responseObject);
                      }
                  }];

    [uploadTask resume];
```